# How to get user's Facebook page list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is what i am looking for. I have successfully logged user to Facebook using FB.api and now i need to fetch the user's Facebook page list (page status is already changed to Published). I have one Facebook App which i am using to fetch Facebook page list and one FB login button through which the user login enabled. My code looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
     <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-  1.7.1.min.js">       </script>
  </head>
<body>
<script>
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.authResponse.userID;
            document.getElementById('access').innerHTML = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
           document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
              'into this app.';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
              'into Facebook.';
        }
    }
    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }
    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
              'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
        FB.api('/me/accounts', 'GET', '', function (response) {
                alert("On get");
                console.log(response);
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
                }
                else {
                    if (response.data.length > 0) { //-- Check for page list
                        alert("On page List")
                        acc_token = response.data[0].access_token; //== Change Accesstoken If a page is exist
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("On NOT");
                    }

                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
  <div id="access"></div>
    <div id="page"></div>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>

  <script>

  (function (d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=810475512349563&   version=v2.0";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="manage_pages" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-  faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" onlogin="checkLoginState();" ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

please note that i used

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="manage_pages" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-  faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" onlogin="checkLoginState();" ></div>
```

for user login and to get page list. But it always returns "data []".

Answer (score 1):

You are defining 2 different solutions for login: The Login Button AND FB.login. Choose the Login Button if you want to use the Facebook Button, choose FB.login if you want to use your own Login Button design.

That being said, the Login Button does not have the necessary scope parameter:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="manage_pages" ...></div>
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button

Btw, there is something really wrong with your code. `window.fbAsyncInit` should be used on page load, not on button click. And FB.login is unneccessary, because it gets called after using the Login Button.

Also, make sure you are trying with a user who is Admin of the App, else you would have to go through the review process first: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

Comment: I will explain it with actual scenario. We have some customers who have their own Facebook business pages attached with their own Facebook accounts. So in our application we have one option to promote their offers which created through our application to their Facebook pages. So in order to do that i created one Facebook app and using that app i successfully logged the user and now i need to fetch that user's Facebook business page list. So that we can show one popup with these fetched page lists and the user can select the pages in which they wish to post their offers.

Comment: well, i see no problem in using different Apps, as long as the user authorizes with an account that is a page admin.

Comment: Then what will be the problem with my code, why it is not returning the user pages.

Comment: are you trying with a user who is admin of the app? make sure the manage_pages permission is mentioned in the login popup.

Comment: the code looks exactly as above. I added scope manage_pages and myself is the admin of the App. Is there is any problem in this

js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=810475512349563&version=v2.0";

Comment: are you trying on a real server or from your computer?

Comment: I am trying it from localhost.

Comment: are there any errors in the browser console? are the app settings correct? did you add a platform for localhost?

Comment: no errors so far and in my app, under basic settings tab, for site URL i already added my local host with port adddress ("http://localhost:1972/").

Comment: and FB.api('/me'... works? because if THAT works, then there can only be 2 reasons for the problem: -) the permission is NOT set correctly (you should get a red warning sign as app admin in the login popup, btw) OR the authorized user is not an admin of any page. make sure to check that out.

Comment: Yes after FB.api('/me', function (response) {} call my console logs with 'Successful login for: ' + response.name. That means it works. And for my App using graph explorer i set permissions including manage-pages.

Comment: then there is something wrong with the authorization for sure. can you post a screenshot of the login popup?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64710/discussion-on-answer-by-luschn-how-to-get-users-facebook-page-list).

Comment: Anyone with any clue on this?